# Antd Design Table, How to pass whether row selected or not selected to expandRowRender

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am using nested tables, in ant design. If I select a row in the top-level table, It should select all the values in nested tables for that row. If I deselect any one of the rows in the nested table it should deselect the row in the top-level table.

I am trying to use the state to control selectedRowKeys, but could not be able to manage all the cases

[image]

Comment: Please provide code or a screenshot of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you, I have added the Image, ABC DEF is the top-level row, If I select that row, it should select all the rows in the nested table.
if any of the row in the nested table is deselected, then the top-level row should get deselected.

Comment: Apologies for the late reply. Work kept me busy. Please see below for a possible solution to your desired UX.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the desired UX via the `rowSelection` prop on the the `Table` component. You will have to determine `onSelect` which of 4 possible cases has taken place (selected a parent row, deselected a parent row, selected a child row or deselected a child row) and then programmatically set `rowSelectionKeys` via a state updater.

You will also a need to create a hash map (`childToParentMap`) from the `Table` `dataSource` in order to track which rows are children and their associated parent row in order to deactivate the parent row on deselection of any one child.

Please see the CodeSandbox example below for a working example of your desired use case:

https://codesandbox.io/s/antdprogrammaticcontrolofnestedtablerowselection-zo7oo?file=/index.js:1888-1913

Happy Coding!

Comment: Thank you very much.!! I have used the same logic that you have mentioned before. I think (not sure) the solution will work only when both the tables have the same columns. In this problem, I have to show nested tables, the top-level table is different from the low-level table. I have used the same logic by maintaining row selected keys and achieved. Please correct me if I am wrong. Once again thank you very much for your help